# How does thrust decide kernel sizes?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia, thrust

When using `thrust` transformations to perform calculation on the device ([saxpy example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/saxpy.cu)), how does thrust figure out the kernel's parameter like `blockSize` and `gridSize`?

Comment: [SO] has a pretty good search and tag history facility. You should use it. This question was only asked a while ago and was still on the first page of recent thrust questions.

Comment: You are right. Honestly I looked at the top votes and could not find it; thought it was not asked before. Voted to close